# NodeJS async function to create Page loader

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, async-await

I know that if we have `await` in our `async function` then the function will be paused until the `await` has been done so I wonder that if can we use the waiting time to create a page loader? If possible, please help me do that! Thanks!

My **app.js** is here:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
require('dotenv/config');

// set up template engine;
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

// static file; middleware;
app.use(express.static('public'));
app.use('/post', express.static('/public'));

// middleware;
const homeRoute = require('./controllers/home');
app.use('/', homeRoute);
const postsRoute = require('./controllers/posts');
app.use('/posts', postsRoute);


// connect to mongodb;
mongoose.connect(
    process.env.DB_CONNECTION,
    { useNewUrlParser: true},
    function(){
        console.log('Connected to db');
    }
);

// listen to port;
app.listen(3000);
```

And my **posts.js** is here:

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const Post = require('../models/posts');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const urlencodedParser = bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false});

router.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.render('post');
});
router.get('/post_render', async function(req, res){
    try {
        let post = await Post.find();             **HERE I WANT TO HAVE A PAGE LOADER**
        res.render('post_render', {data: post});  **DURING WAITING FOR THE DATA TO BE FOUND**
    } catch (err) {
        res.json({message: err});
    }

})

router.post('/', urlencodedParser, async function(req, res){
    let post = new Post({
        title: req.body.title,
        description: req.body.description
    });
    try {
        let savePost = await post.save(); // 
        res.redirect('/posts/post_render');  
    } catch(err){
        res.json({message: err});
    }
});

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: What is a "page loader"?  What does it do?  You're using a non-standard term as a central part of your question which makes the question unclear.

Comment: Sorry about my vocabulary. I dont know exactly what we call it. It just a loading circle when we move from current page to another page.

Comment: Btw it's called a spinner/loader.

Answer (score 3):

A spinning circle in the browser, often called a "spinner" (which is apparently what you mean by a "page loader") is a client-side thing.  It will have to be implemented in client-side HTML or Javascript.  It could be done client-side only for routes that were requested from an Ajax call in the browser, not from routes that were requested via a redirect or a direct link to a new page from the browser.

The issue is that as soon as the browser starts requesting a new page, it clears the current page contents (so you can't put the spinner in the old page).  The new page contents are not displayed until enough of the new page has arrived to being parsing and displaying the HTML (it is displayed progressively as soon as a chunk of self contained HTML arrives, is parsed and isn't too dependent upon other resources that are not yet loaded.

Your current code does this:

```
    let post = await Post.find();             **HERE I WANT TO HAVE A PAGE LOADER**
    res.render('post_render', {data: post});  **DURING WAITING FOR THE DATA TO BE FOUND**
```

That means during the time you want the spinner displayed, you haven't sent ANY HTML to the browser.  So, all the browser will have done is cleared the prior page and be sitting there with an empty page waiting for some parseable HTML content to arrive.  Since you're sending the HTML only after your database lookup, nothing will have arrived to the browser that could show the spinner.  So, this code, the way it is written will not be able to show a spinner.

You can show a spinner during an Ajax call.  The host page, shows the spinner, makes the Ajax call and then hides the spinner when the Ajax call is done.

---

I've never tried this, but it might be theoretically possible for this sequence:

```
  res.write(partA)
  let post = await Post.find();
  res.render('post_render', {data: post}, function (err, partB) {
      if (err) {
          res.write(partX);
      } else {
          res.write(partB);
      }
      res.end();
  });
```

In this code, you'd have the following pieces of HTML:

**partA** - The first part of an HTML page that allowed the browser to begin parsing the page and display a spinner (either entirely with HTML or with HTML and Javascript).  This cannot be a whole page, it must be partial, unfinished page, but something the browser feels safe to begin parsing and displaying even while it is waiting for the rest of the page.

**partB** - The rest of the HTML page that goes with partA.  This would hide the previous spinner (likely with Javascript) and then provide the rest of the HTML for the page.  partA + partB would make a fully formatted, legal HTML page.

**partX** - This is an alternative second part of the page that goes with partA that would be displayed when there was a rendering error.

---

Another possibility would be for your route to send a fully formatted placeholder page that shows a shell of your content and puts up the spinner.  Included in that placeholder page would be some Javascript that requests the actual data or rendered HTML for the page via an Ajax call to a different route.  When the Ajax call succeeds, your Javascript would insert that content into the page and hide the spinner.  This is probably a lot simpler than the partA/partB idea above.

Comment: @Andrew-Vangeance - Did this answer your question?